# Is there anyway I can get every color(rgb) image's pixel matching which depth(ir) image's pixel?

Tags: kinect, camera-calibration

I use Kinect2.0. I already got the intrinsic parameters of the depth camera and color camera, and extrinsic parameters between them.

Now I already know every depth(ir) image's pixel match which color(rgb) image's pixel.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 424; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp_dp, "%lf", &depthValue);

            if (depthValue == 0) continue;

            double Pir[3][1] = { j*depthValue, i*depthValue, depthValue };

            P_ir = Mat(3, 1, CV_64F, Pir);
            P_rgb = Mat(3, 1, CV_64F);
            P_rgb = Intrinsic_rgb*(R_ir2rgb*(Intrinsic_ir_inv*P_ir) + T_ir2rgb);

            int x = P_rgb.at<double>(0, 0) / depthValue;
            int y = P_rgb.at<double>(1, 0) / depthValue;
            //printf("(%d,%d)\n", x, y);

            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= 1920 || y >= 1080)
            {
                continue;
            }
            img_mmap.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = img_rgb.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0];
            img_mmap.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = img_rgb.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
            img_mmap.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = img_rgb.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2];

            Color_depth[y][x] = depthValue;
        }
        fscanf(fp_dp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fp_dp);
    imwrite(ir_name, img_mmap);
```

As you can see I want get the color image's depth data. But when I use this method. I just got 512x424 units data. It's not 1920x1080.

So Is there anyway I can know every color(rgb) image's pixel match which depth(ir) image's pixel when I already get the intrinsic parameters of the two cameras and the extrinsic parameters between them?

Comment: So you scan thru the depth image and transform to the RGB in order to fill it? You must do the opposite: you inverse transform from the RGB-grid coordinates and linearly interpolate it's values from the depth image. I guess it makes sense to store the depth image as `cv::Mat` and use transform functions available. (not sure though what `H_ir_inv` and others are).

Comment: Thanks, H_ir_inv is inverse of depth camera intrinsic parameters. I already use interpolation. but I'm afraid of it's not correct.  So I want know every color(rgb) image's pixel match which depth(ir) image's pixel. Then I can thru the match point, get the depth value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MapColorFrameToDepthSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.coordinatemapper.mapcolorframetodepthspace.aspx).

Remark:

> Allocate the `depthSpacePoints` array before calling this method. It
>   should have the same number of elements as the color frame has pixels
>   (1920px by 1080px). Each entry in the filled depthSpacePoints array
>   contains the depth point to which the corresponding pixel belongs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. ^v^.

Comment: Please appreciate with upvote and correct answer mark, if it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: I will be back when I grow up, Thanks a lot. ^V^.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... anyway, though you can't upvote, you can choose an answer as accepted among the answers of the question you asked. To accept a answer of a question that you asked, need no initial reputation, also, you get +2 reputation when you mark an answer as accepted. For more [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: As your say, I get 15 reputation. 0.0

Comment: Thanks a lot :), you can update your 'about me' with your twitter or fb link so that we can follow you.